# SQL Server Authorization Denied in Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, authorization

I have a working C# application that requires connection to a SQL database that uses Windows authentication. However while I can connect to the database just fine with Server Management Studio and SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio, I get a "User not authorized to use the system" whenever I run the application and the application tries to connect to the database.

The same application works for the other members of the team, and at some point it worked for me as well. I definitely have access to the database. The only recent change I can think of is I re-installed Visual Studio and Server Management Studio.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a SQL error, is that a custom error your app throws when connection fails or could it be something else?

Comment: Yes it is a custom error the application throws when the user does not have access to the database.

Comment: Can you trap the exact SQL exception?

Comment: Are you connecting to Server using mdf file name or are you using the same login as with SQL Server.  Never connect to database using mdf filename because credentials are different than connecting with database and you may get locked out of mdf file due to database being the owner of the file.

Answer (score 0):

While I was looking for the exact SQL exception, I found a function that checks if the user is in the group ReadWriteOnly. However I am in the group DB_OWNER.

Upon changing the function to accept both ReadWriteOnly and DB_OWNER, the application can connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

**In Case you are running SQL Server on your local Development machine**

SQL services stop running automatically so you have to start them manually . Go to services.msc , look for SQL server service and start them .

**Look for log**

Apart from this check logs on your local machine using eventvwr tool, look for application log under Windows log section. This is usually helpful